# Error building python package on makefile even though I have the package installed

Tags: python, makefile, mypy

I am trying to run makefile for a certain project but I got lots of error during make run even when everything was successful when running make init. Currently I run this makefile on conda environment

I have even checked the file that has error and run it directly using python blablabla.py and it run perfectly yet when I run the makefile it shows up as an error on the same file

```
all: build

init:
    @which python3 > /dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "python3 is not installed on this system" && exit 1)
    @which pip3 > /dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "pip3 is not installed on this system" && exit 1)
    @echo "Installing requirements with pip3..."
    @while read package; \
    do \
      line="$$package"; \
      [[ "$$line" == git+* ]] && \
        line=`echo "$$line" | sed -e 's/git.*\///g' -e 's/.git$$//g'`; \
      pip3 freeze 2>/dev/null | grep -P `echo "$$line" | sed 's/>=/.*/g'` > /dev/null 2>&1 || \
        pip3 install --user "$$package"; \
    done < requirements.txt

build: init build-lang
    @echo "Building python package..."
    @mypy --package color_harmonization
    @echo "#! /bin/bash" > color-harmonization
    @echo "/usr/bin/env python3 -m color_harmonization" >> color-harmonization
    @chmod +x color-harmonization

run: build
    @echo "Running application..."
    @./color-harmonization

lang:
    @echo "Generating internationalization files..."
    @mkdir -p color_harmonization/gui/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES
    @intltool-extract --type=gettext/glade color_harmonization/gui/color-harmonization.glade
    @xgettext --from-code=UTF-8 --language=Python --keyword=_ --keyword=N_ \
    --output=color_harmonization/gui/locale/locale.pot \
    `find . -name "*.py" -type f` \
    color_harmonization/gui/color-harmonization.glade.h
    @msginit --input=color_harmonization/gui/locale/locale.pot \
    --locale=de_DE.UTF-8 --output-file=color_harmonization/gui/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/de_DE.po

build-lang:
    @echo "Compiling internationalization files..."
    @msgfmt --output color_harmonization/gui/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/color_harmonization.mo \
    color_harmonization/gui/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/de_DE.po
```

These are the error from building the makefile

```
Compiling internationalization files...
Building python package...
color_harmonization/gui/gl_widget.py:21: error: No library stub file for module 'gi.repository'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_widget.py:22: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'OpenGL'
color_harmonization/gui/__init__.py:19: error: Name 'List' is not defined
color_harmonization/gui/__init__.py:19: note: Did you forget to import it from "typing"? (Suggestion: "from typing import List")
color_harmonization/__init__.py:19: error: Name 'List' is not defined
color_harmonization/__init__.py:19: note: Did you forget to import it from "typing"? (Suggestion: "from typing import List")
color_harmonization/handler.py:20: error: No library stub file for module 'gi.repository'
color_harmonization/gui/hue_sat_wheel_widget.py:20: error: No library stub file for module 'numpy'
color_harmonization/gui/hue_sat_wheel_widget.py:22: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'cairocffi'
color_harmonization/gui/hue_sat_wheel_widget.py:25: error: No library stub file for module 'gi.repository'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_quad_renderer.py:19: error: No library stub file for module 'numpy'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_quad_renderer.py:23: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'OpenGL'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_quad_renderer.py:24: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'pyrr'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_quad_renderer.py:25: error: No library stub file for module 'PIL'
color_harmonization/gui/gl_image.py:19: error: No library stub file for module 'gi.repository'
color_harmonization/gui/assistant.py:24: error: No library stub file for module 'gi.repository'
color_harmonization/gui/assistant.py:24: note: (Stub files are from https://github.com/python/typeshed)
color_harmonization/gui/assistant.py:39: error: Module has no attribute "bindtextdomain"
color_harmonization/gui/assistant.py:104: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "List[str]")
color_harmonization/gui/assistant.py:105: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "str")
color_harmonization/__main__.py:22: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'gi'
color_harmonization/__main__.py:22: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 18 errors in 9 files (checked 12 source files)
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

This is one of the python file since there are lots of it, I only post the first python file on error

```
import abc

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from OpenGL import GL

class GLRenderer (metaclass = abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    def gl_widget (self: 'GLRenderer') -> 'GLWidget':
        return self.__gl_widget

    @gl_widget.setter
    def gl_widget (self: 'GLRenderer', value: 'GLWidget') -> None:
        self.__gl_widget = value

    def make_current (self: 'GLRenderer') -> None:
        self.gl_widget.make_current ()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load (self: 'GLRenderer') -> None:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def update (self: 'GLRenderer') -> None:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def resize (self: 'GLRenderer', width: int, height: int) -> None:
        GL.glViewport (0, 0, width, height)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def render (self: 'GLRenderer') -> None:
        GL.glClear (GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        GL.glClearColor (0, 0, 0, 0)

class GLWidget (Gtk.Overlay):
    def __init__ (self: 'GLWidget', renderer: GLRenderer,
                  gl_major_version: int, gl_minor_version: int) -> None:
        super ().__init__ ()

        self.renderer = renderer
        self.renderer.gl_widget = self

        self.gl_area = Gtk.GLArea ()
        self.gl_area.set_required_version (gl_major_version, gl_minor_version)
        self.gl_area.props.has_alpha = True
        self.gl_area.props.has_depth_buffer = False
        self.gl_area.props.auto_render = True
        self.gl_area.connect ('render', self.__handle_render)
        self.gl_area.connect ('realize', self.__handle_realize)
        self.gl_area.connect ('resize', self.__handle_resize)

        self.add_overlay (self.gl_area)
        self.props.expand = True

        self.__width = 400
        self.__height = 300

    def __handle_render (self: 'GLWidget', gl_area: Gtk.GLArea, context: Gdk.GLContext) -> None:
        self.renderer.render ()

    def __handle_realize (self: 'GLWidget', gl_area: Gtk.GLArea) -> None:
        self.renderer.load ()

    def __handle_resize (self: 'GLWidget', gl_area: Gtk.GLArea, width: int, height: int) -> None:
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
        self.renderer.resize (width, height)

    @property
    def width (self: 'GLWidget') -> int:
        return self.__width

    @property
    def height (self: 'GLWidget') -> int:
        return self.__height

    def make_current (self: 'GLWidget') -> None:
        self.gl_area.make_current ()
```

Please check this [github link](https://github.com/fin-ger/color-harmonization) for complete source code. I would appreciate any suggestion and help thank you

Comment: the makefile does `./color-harmonization` but you do `python gl_widget.py`. that is not the same. also i think the problem is in the python source. please post relevant python source. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. The reason I do `python gl_widge.py` is because I thought if it successfully compile independently then it should have worked when compiled as a whole. But since you said it is not the same, I have already edited my post based on what you suggest. I hope it is the one that you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be mypy not finding the modules. The modules seem to be installed fine on your system as evident when you run `python gl_widget.py` without import errors.

Please study the mypy manual and implement the steps mentioned there: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#finding-imports

If that does not solve your problem or you still have questions then please ask another question. This time not tagged makefile but only mypy and python. Because this is not a makefile problem but a mypy and python module finding problem.

Also, since your username is "wanttobepro", learning to do minimal reproducible examples is very helpful on your quest to be a pro. Please learn to do minimal reproducible examples.

Read here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

and even more: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=minimal+reproducible+examples&t=ffab&ia=web